# In Excel, Choosing a Word from a List

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't want a drop-down list. When I search the web for this answer, I always wind up reading about drop-down lists.

I want Excel to fill a cell with a word automatically, based on the value in another cell.

For example I want to compute a value in cell A1, and based on that value, I want another cell A2 to contain "Alabama" if A1=1, "Alaska" if A1=2, etc.

A bad way to do this would be a series of If's. Insert into cell A2 the rule =If(A1=1, "Alabama", if (A1=2, "Alaska", if (A1=3, "Arizona"…

I think that there's a way to include the list in a spreadsheet, and tell Excel to fill A2 with the item on the list that corresponds with the value in A1.

I don't know which versions of Excel I will be using. I work in a building with lots of computers, and I use various computers through each week, both PC's and Mac's.

If this is not the correct Stack Exchange for this question, I would be grateful for advice in finding the correct Stack Exchange.

PS As I typed this letter, a remark appeared in the right margin of the screen telling me that a similar question asked about "auto-populating" a cell. That seems probably right, except that the linked question did not get a good answer. So I post here and hope for the best.

Comment: Try [VLOOKUP()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **A2** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(A1,"Alabama","Alaska","Arizona")
```

[image]

If the list is large, I suggest using a `VLOOKUP()` table instead:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE)
```

[image]